# How do i get any file signature (or call it file header) in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a module which uploads images, pdfs, audio and video files. I mainly covered all the validations in it but i am stuck at one point where i cannot detect the header of the video/audio file. It is when i change the type of any file, like changed the .JS to mp3 or mp4. Is there any packages in nodeJS which can detect the file signature or header?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not/do not, want to check by the filename extension you will have to parse the file using an appropriate media inspector.

To list a few:

- [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type)
- [mux.js](https://github.com/videojs/mux.js)